# ORA-02253 ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE XX_EMP_COL_CONST
(
    EMP_ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT XX_EMP_COL_CONST_PK PRIMARY KEY,
    ENAME VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT XX_EMP_COL_CONST_UK1 UNIQUE,
    SALARY NUMBER NOT NULL,
    GENDER CHAR (1) CONSTRAINT XX_EMP_COL_CONST_CHQ CHECK (GENDER IN ('M','F')),
    DEPT_ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT XX_EMP_COL_CONST_FK1 REFERENCE departments(department_id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try (you made just a simple mistake: the S after REFERENCE):

```
CREATE TABLE XX_EMP_COL_CONST (
    EMP_ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT XX_EMP_COL_CONST_PK PRIMARY KEY
    ,ENAME VARCHAR2(100) CONSTRAINT XX_EMP_COL_CONST_UK1 UNIQUE
    ,SALARY NUMBER NOT NULL
    ,GENDER CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT XX_EMP_COL_CONST_CHQ CHECK (GENDER IN ('M', 'F'))
    ,DEPT_ID NUMBER CONSTRAINT XX_EMP_COL_CONST_FK1 REFERENCES departments(department_id)
    );
```

You can see it on  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e896f/1